# How to write hex values in byte array?

Tags: c#

I have a hex value of 0x1047F71 and I want to put in byte array of 4 bytes. Is this the right way to do it:

```
byte[] sync_welcome_sent = new byte[4] { 0x10, 0x47, 0xF7, 0x01 };
```

or

```
byte[] sync_welcome_sent = new byte[4] { 0x01, 0x04, 0x7F, 0x71 };
```

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: I'd probably use `BitConverter.GetBytes`... but your first version is *definitely* inappropriate, as it would effectively give 0x1047f701. What are you trying to *do* with those bytes afterwards though? That will determine what endianness you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to be compatible with Intel little-endian, the answer is "None of the above", because the answer would be "71h, 7fh, 04h, 01h".

For big-endian, the second answer above is correct: "01h, 04h, 7fh, 71h".

You can get the bytes with the following code:

```
uint test = 0x1047F71;
var bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(test);
```

If you want big-endian, you can just reverse the bytes using Linq like so:

```
var bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(test).Reverse();
```

However, if you are running the code on a Big Endian system, reversing the bytes will not be necessary, since `BitConverter.GetBytes()`will return them as big endian on a big endian system.

Therefore you should write the code as follows:

```
uint test = 0x1047F71;
var bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(test);

if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
    bytes = bytes.Reverse().ToArray();

// now bytes[] are big-endian no matter what system the code is running on.
```